# Squirrel - changing driver properties not possible

Tags: properties, driver, squirrel-sql

I use Squirrel 3.8.1 and try to configure a connection to Amazon Redshift via driver `RedshiftJDBC42-1.2.1.1001.jar`.
However, I am not able to change the properties of the driver which are listed in tab `Driver properties`.
I check the `Specify` box and in the column `Value` a `?` appears. But the field is not editable.

Answer (score 0):

I just come across the same problem with the Athena driver.  Found a workaround to the problem you describe above.  Right click the properties table then select 'Add', you can then add the relevant properties, just make sure you click the 'Specify' box for the new value.